# How to migrate a project made in Laravel 4.0 to Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, laravel-upgrade

I'm setting up a new server and want to migrate the project from Laravel version 4.0 to Laravel version 5. I followed the steps mentioned in this URL [Upgrading from Laravel 4 to Laravel 5](https://mattstauffer.com/blog/upgrading-from-laravel-4-to-laravel-5/), but after all the steps, I got the following error. What could be the reason?

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError] Fatal error:
> Class name must be a valid object or a string
>
> ```
> Exception trace:
>  () at /home/vagrant/work/laravel/vendor/zizaco/entrust/src/commands/MigrationCommand.php:86
>  Zizaco\Entrust\MigrationCommand->createMigration() at /home/vagrant/work/laravel/vendor/zizaco/entrust/src/commands/MigrationCommand.php:58
>  Zizaco\Entrust\MigrationCommand->fire() at n/a:n/a
>  call_user_func_array() at /home/vagrant/work/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:507
>  Illuminate\Container\Container->call() at /home/vagrant/work/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:169
>  Illuminate\Console\Command->execute() at /home/vagrant/work/laravel/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:256
>  Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /home/vagrant/work/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:155
>  Illuminate\Console\Command->run() at /home/vagrant/work/laravel/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:791
>  Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /home/vagrant/work/laravel/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:186
>  Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /home/vagrant/work/laravel/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:117
>  Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /home/vagrant/work/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:107
>  Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle() at /home/vagrant/work/laravel/artisan:35
> ```

Comment: @RiggsFolly I followed the standard migration steps provided by site which is https://mattstauffer.com/blog/upgrading-from-laravel-4-to-laravel-5/

Comment: why not install fresh one instead of cloning

Comment: @GauravGupta We have lots of Data and Code is done from 2 years of efforts. Creating new one would be very time taking

Comment: the url you have mention above tell you to make clone of laravel 5 and then move all of your file in which i am telling you to install of fresh one if you are geting error in clone

Comment: @GauravGupta I see, sorry I misinterpreted your question. Yes, have followed the same scenario already

Comment: You didn't try [upgrade solutions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/upgrade) from official site?

Comment: there might be problem with direct upgrade 4.0-5.2 because as mention on site need to go step over step

Comment: @Tpojka Yes, first we try from the official site, but got a bunch of Fatal errors and class errors, after spending so much time, finally we decided to follow above steps where most of the error are solved only above error is coming now.

Comment: @GauravGupta you are right Gaurav.

Comment: You need to read and go from bottom of the page up, from [this section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/upgrade) and going up level by level. Have you done that?

Comment: @Tpojka we thoroughly followed the same document, as there was some code which was customized by our side, so we remove the custom code and replace with the default CORE laravel code.

Comment: Did you tried Laravel Shift ?
https://laravelshift.com/

Answer (score 2):

Do yourself a favour and use [Laravel Shift](https://laravelshift.com/upgrade-laravel-4.2-to-laravel-5.0). Upgrade Laravel 4.2 to Laravel 5.0
The Laravel 5.0 Shift automates the upgrade from Laravel 4.2 to Laravel 5.0. Using the Laravel 5.0 Shift to automatically upgrade your Laravel application has an estimated time savings of over 6 hours.